# Arquivos .sass não compilam

Tags: github, sass, jekyll

Estou trabalhando num projeto usando Jekyll com Github Pages.

Estou tentando usar um arquivo `.sass`, salvando-o na pasta `_sass`, usando a sintaxe recomendada pelo site do jekyll:

```
---
---

.page-header
  background: #333
  padding: 1em
  text-align: center
```

O arquivo entretanto não compila para o arquivo final `main.css` na pasta `_site/css`.

O que devo fazer para trabalhar com arquivos `.sass` no Jekyll?

Comment: Quando você tenta compilar ele dá algum erro ou simplesmente não compila?

Comment: Aparentemente ele não compila. Pelo menos o terminal não retorna nenhum erro.

Answer (score 2):

Eu esqueci de fazer o import do arquivo `.sass` no final do arquivo `css/main.scss`:

```
@import
    "base",
    "layout",
    "syntax-highlighting",
    "header" /* nome do meu arquivo .sass, sem a extensão */
;
```

Agora está funcionando perfeitamente.